# Python Mechanize/BeautifulSoup Scraping (Iterating over Dictionaries)

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am currently scraping a site using BS and Mechanize, and I was able to get my scraper working for an instance, but I want to iterate over a dictionary, inserting a value each type it loops. Because I am a total noob to python (my apologies), I am having trouble understanding how to do just that.

See code below for one value:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

ids = csv.DictReader(open("csv_to_scrape.csv"))
persons = [person for person in ids]

br = mechanize.Browser()
br2 = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br2.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.open('https://www.example.com')

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['licenseNumber'] = '012345' #This is the value that comes from my dict. 
br.submit()

for link in br.links(url_regex="/details"):
    req = br.click_link(url=link.url)
    html = br2.open(req).read()

soup = BS(html)
text1 = soup.find('div', {'class':'infobox append-bottom span-11'}).text
text2 = soup.find('div', {'class':'infobox append-bottom'}).text

f = open('output.csv', 'w')
x = '012345'
write_to_file = x + "," + '"""' + text2 + '"""' + "," + '"""' + text1 + '"""' + "\n"
write_to_unicode = write_to_file.encode('utf-8')
print x
f.write(write_to_unicode)
f.close()
```

I have a basic dict that looks like this:

```
[{'': '3008', 'name': 'Doe, John', 'date': '05-09-89', 'location': 'New York, NY', 'action': 'Dance', 'id': '012345'}, {'': '3080', 'name': 'Smith, John', 'date': '12-04-92', 'location': 'San Francisco, CA', 'action': 'Singing', 'id': '543210'}, etc.....
```

I am trying to iterate with 'id', putting it into the form below where 'licenseNumber' is and then append it to another dict or write it to a csv.

I know this is probably very easy (and basic), but I've been stuck for two days (putting in 10 hours a day). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm unsure if the problem code is actually shown in the code sample or not. It doesn't seem to be?

Comment: And can you expand and clarify what you mean by " I am trying to iterate with 'id', putting it into the form below where 'licenseNumber' is and then append it to another dict or write it to a csv"?

Comment: Did the answer below assist?  Can you further explain your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Getting an item from your dictionary is incredibly easy in python.  Just call the `get` method on the dictionary and pass it the key you want.  For example: `dictionary.get(key)`.  In your case, your `key` would be your 'id.'

Because you show a list of dictionaries and you mention iteration, here's a quick line of code to extract all of the ids from your list of dictionaries.

```
list_of_ids = [_dict.get("id") for _dict in list_of_dicts]
```

That's it.  Now you can iterate over the list and input the id into your form -- which may mean that you need to nest your current `for loop` but it's not clear from your code, so I won't say.

I hope that helps, and I apologize if I'm totally misinterpreting your question.